# Удалить cookies определенного домена

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

Так случилось, что сайт устанавливал сначала *cookies* c именем `city_id` для домена `domain.ru`. Впоследствии много чего изменилось и теперь эта же самая *cookies* c именем `city_id`, но уже с доменом `.domain.ru`.

Фактически это разные *cookies*. Хочется удалить всем пользователям *cookies*, которая с доменом `domain.ru`.

Пробую так:

```
$.cookie('city_id', null, {domain: 'domain.ru', path: '/', expires: -1 });
```

Но не работает. А если в значении *domain* указать `.domain.ru` (с точкой), соответственно удаляется не та *cookies*.

Как можно решить эту проблему и удалить нужную куку с доменом `domain.ru`?

Comment: Раз через js не получается, почему не попробовать с сайта ее установить?

Comment: Попробуйте не указывать `path`, а `expires` устанавливать не в -1, а во «вчера».